# Standard Report Functionality - Is there a way to display Bounced HTML emails?

Tags: apex, visualforce, email, reporting

At reports in section Activity there is a type HTML Emails to track emais send with the standard HTML emails functionality. This can be used to somehow monitor the sent emails with the standard mass mailing tools.

But it seems some information, which is available at other places in Salesforce is not available in this report - but it should:

- bounced emails
- more activity and related fields (custom and standard)

Is there any way to get a more sophisticated overview of sent mass mailings?

(I know Exact Target, Pardot and other tools but there use-cases without sufficient budget for that)